# An ancient text arguing that an assembly with no opposition should be dissolved

Tags: sources-mekorot, responsa, sanhedrin

In Benjamin Aryeh Hakohen Weiss's "Even Yekarah” (Choshen Mishpat, sec. 20) it refers to an ancient gentile text which specifies that when the state government has no minority/opposition members, it should be dissolved and reappointed because of the importance of opposition. Can anyone help me identify the ancient text to which he refers?

Here is a translation of the relevant section:

> 34 voting to convict would result in a conviction, a decision by all
> 71 to convict would result in an acquittal!
>
> I answered that he was quite right [about the talmudic ruling].
> According to what was said in a book by one of the ancient gentile
> sages, in the part discussing state government, any assembly that does
> not have an opposition, a minority opposed to the majority, does not
> fulfill its calling, and should be dissolved and new assemblymen
> appointed. Because in the nature of things, every man is capable of
> error—and not only individuals; in any given matter, large groups can
> err as well. And so there is a need for sifting the truth from
> conflicting arguments, as the holder of each respective opinion
> strives to establish his view through arguments and analogies and thus
> vanquish opposing views. And if, after the airing of differing views,
> the majority chooses to accept one of them, it is clear that that is
> the true one. But this is not the case if only one view is presented
> without opposing evidence and arguments, [for] that does not create
> the debate necessary for determining true views. After all, all their
> intellects could have been captivated by error, thus being mistaken in
> judgment, and so the assembled group has not fulfilled its required
> goal.
>
> Thus the words of our sages are quite just. For the Sanhedrin was a
> gathering of sages with the responsibility to adjudicate matters of
> life and death: whether to afflict or to show mercy. Hence, if with
> regard to a given matter, some moved to convict and others to acquit,
> there was then a genuine debate necessary to arrive at the truth.
> Then, if after [the debate], the majority of sages gathered there
> agreed to convict the defendant standing before them, their judgment
> is free of doubt, and the defendant is definitely guilty, and their
> decision is true and their judgment just. But if there were only
> judges voting to convict, with nobody to contest their view, no one
> working to demonstrate the truth of alternative reasoning, it is only
> natural that they may all have erred, and thus that they will spill an
> innocent's blood. And so their words are just, [namely] that if all of
> them vote to convict, the defendant shall go free and not be condemned
> by the judgment of this panel, which may simply be seeing things
> incorrectly.
>
> And my wise interlocutor saw my point [about our sages] and proceeded
> to sing their praises.

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/67989/1144